# Is there a hinge which will move both connected doors when just a single door is moved?

Tags: kitchens, hinges

I'm about to finish setting up a new IKEA kitchen, and I'm now trying to fit a non-IKEA integrated dishwasher into it. As many apparently before me have discovered, this is not "plug and play" (unless you've got one of a few special models that fit IKEA kitchens). The wooden IKEA kitchen door fronts are simply too high to be fitted on my dishwasher.

If you look at the drawing below, the front (**A** + **B**) will go too far down towards the floor and consequently hit the dishwasher when opening it.

So, I've been thinking. I could split the front into two sections, so that I have a section **A** and section **B**. Section **A** would be attached to the dishwasher, and section **B** would be "hanging" / attached to section **A** via some sort of hinge connecting the bottom of section **A** to the top of section **B**. That's the easy part.

Now, when opening the dishwasher I would like section **B** to move towards section **A** in an outward direction (see section position 2 in the drawing).

Does such a hinge (or similar mechanism) exists? One that, when section **A** moves, section **B** will move as well in an outward direction?

It doesn't have to be a hinge though. It could be a mechanism where the default position of **B** was - say - 45 degrees outwards towards section **A**. 
The more section **A** would go towards an upright position, the more it would pull section **B** "back" towards an upright position as well.

I'm open to all ideas. The only limitations are :

1. Section **B** must be attached to section **A** because the bottom of section **A** is 15mm lower towards the floor when opened than when closed. I don't want to fit section **B** with such a large gap below section **A**. I can eliminate this gap if i attach section **B** to section A.
2. I'd rather not have section **B** just "hanging" in a normal hinge under section **A**, as section **B** then would become a 90 degrees tilted saloon door going back and forth with the slightest touch.

[image]

Comment: Search "geared continuous hinges" or "geared door hinges" – is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @feetwet wow! Yes, the search results for that is absolutely what I was thinking of. This answers my question. Your'e welcome to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Why does B need to move at all? Why can't you fix it in position 1 to the floor or edges of adjacent cabinets or something, so only A moves?

Comment: @FredShope because by doing that would have to leave a 15mm gap between bottom of A and top of B as A will be 15mm closer to the floor when open compared to when it is closed. That 15mm gap will not look nice.

Comment: That depends on what type of hinge you use, there are many that have very small to no gaps and have various finishes to match your décor. For example, http://www.hardwaresource.com/images/products/thumb_category_400051-lg.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Some variant of "geared continuous hinges" or "geared door hinges" can be adopted to do this.  Examples:

[image: Continuous Geared Hinge]

[image: Full Surface Continuous Hinge]

Answer (score 2):

The adapt-r hinge will solve this problem. 
It can be installed with one or multiple drawer fronts. 
It is like a geared hinge as #feetwet describes but then specially designed for this purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any special hinges for this. Just use a regular hinge and let Part B hang straight down when the door is in up position. When the door is opened Part B can continue to hang straight down as pulled by gravity whilst the Part A door comes down.

Note that I see no benefit what so ever for a geared hinge for this application.

Comment: The drawback with this solution would be that the lower section would be a little like a horizontal saloon door. It will be sliding back and forth every time we come in contact with it (which will happen often because it's in front of sink and dishwasher). I'd rather have a hinge which somehow also will lock the lower section.

Comment: ...unless i can get a regular hinge that will only go outwards, and cannot bend  backwards towards the dishwasher?

Comment: If you have the hinge axis at the front of the part a and part b divide the part edges will contact if the b part was pushed toward the dishwasher.